# Passing data for all views in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a website that had a calculation scores function,
and I want to pass the score for all views in my website.

Laravel version 5.4

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.